# Using combination of simulink and m-script with assert block and callbacks

Tags: matlab, simulink, assert

I used a combination of simulink and m-script with the help of assert block. I already uncheck 'Stop Simulation when assertion fails' in the assert block. Now i want to add three commands:

1. set_param(bdroot,'SimulationCommand','pause');
2. run('myscript.m'); %insert the script name
3. set_param(bdroot,'SimulationCommand','continue');

When I run the second command I get the following error message:

```
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=781/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=781/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=795/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=795/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=797/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=797/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=799/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=799/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=801/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=801/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=803/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=803/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=805/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=805/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=807/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=807/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=809/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=809/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=811/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=811/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=813/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=813/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=777/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=777/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=815/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=815/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=817/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=817/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=819/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=819/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=821/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=821/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=823/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=823/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=825/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=825/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=827/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=827/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=829/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=829/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=831/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=831/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=833/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=833/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=779/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=779/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=835/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=835/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=837/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=837/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=839/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=839/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=841/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=841/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=843/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=843/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=783/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=783/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=785/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=785/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=787/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=787/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=789/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=789/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=791/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=791/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.
[DataProvider              ] WRN: 
Registering: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=793/phong; Already registered: pimp/worldmodelmaterial:uniqueID=793/phong
Interface is registered twice for writing.


An error occurred while running the simulation and the simulation was terminated
Caused by:
Error evaluating 'AssertionFcn' callback of Assertion block 'ADAS001_Kalibrierung_Fehlerfortpflanzung_Var_cs/Box_1/Assertion'.
Not enough input arguments.
Component: Simulink | Category: Block error
```

Also, I can only execute one callback command. How can I execute multiple commands? - I have already tried to separate these commands with , or ;.

Comment: I think you'll find that the simulation automatically pauses while the callback is being executed, so you don't need your first or 3rd line.  The code put into the block is also automatically executed, so you don't need the `run` either.

Comment: Thank you. So i used the Callback in the Assert Block for the first command. I put the other two commands as Callback in Simulink. It works fine!